# Can't link to the harfbuzz dynamic library with Rust FFI

Tags: rust, ffi, harfbuzz

I want to use a Rust file `main.rs` to bind a C file `src/c_ffi/myharfbuzz.c` that links a dynamic library (for example `hb.h` and `hb-ot.h`). When I compile it with `cargo run`, it shows the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: .../target/debug/build/uahji2-109ed7d174e31932/out/libmyharfbuzz.a(myharfbuzz.o): in function `example':
.../src/c_ffi/myharfbuzz.c:18: undefined reference to `hb_blob_create_from_file'
      /usr/bin/ld: .../src/c_ffi/myharfbuzz.c:19: undefined reference to `hb_face_create'
      /usr/bin/ld: .../src/c_ffi/myharfbuzz.c:21: undefined reference to `hb_ot_var_get_axis_count'
      /usr/bin/ld: .../src/c_ffi/myharfbuzz.c:22: undefined reference to `hb_ot_var_get_axis_infos'
```

It seems that `ld` can't find the dynamic library `hb.h`

Here are my files:

### src/main.rs

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

#[link(name = "myharfbuzz")]
extern "C" {
    fn example(s: *const std::os::raw::c_char, a: i32, b: i32);
}

fn main() {
    let prompt = CString::new("Rust").unwrap();

    unsafe {
        example(prompt.as_ptr(), 7, 11);
    }
}
```

### src/c_ffi/myharfbuzz.c

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <hb.h>
#include <hb-ot.h>
#include <stdint.h>



void example(int32_t a, int32_t b){
printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);

char *filename = "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc";
printf("%s", filename);

hb_blob_t *blob = hb_blob_create_from_file(filename);
hb_face_t *face = hb_face_create(blob, 0);
hb_ot_var_axis_info_t *axes_array;
int axes = hb_ot_var_get_axis_count(face);
hb_ot_var_get_axis_infos(face, 0, &axes, axes_array);
printf("%d", axes_array);
}
```

In my `build.rs` the include path was set, but `ld` emitted the linking error:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;
extern crate pkg_config;

fn main() {
    let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    println!("OUT_DIR = {:?}", out_dir);
    let harfbuzz_config = pkg_config::Config::new().probe("harfbuzz").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", harfbuzz_config);

    let linked_path = harfbuzz_config.link_paths[0].clone();

    let mut builder = cc::Build::new();
    builder
        .files(&["src/c_ffi/myharfbuzz.c"])
        .includes(harfbuzz_config.include_paths)
        .includes(harfbuzz_config.link_paths)
        .flag(&format!("-lharfbuzz"))
        .compile(&format!("myharfbuzz"));

    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={:?}", linked_path);
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", out_dir);
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=myharfbuzz");
}
```

Comment: *the dynamic library hb.h* — .h files are headers, not libraries. *the include path* — include paths are for headers, not libraries.

Comment: `hb.h` is not a dynamic library, it's a header file and it is found just fine. The dynamic library is `libharfbuzz.so` and it's not found because you specify it in the wrong place: remove `.flag(&format!("-lharfbuzz"))` and add `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=harfbuzz");`

Comment: Thank you for clearifying the concept betewwn headers and libraries for me. I have make commented `.flag(&format!("-lharfbuzz"))` and add `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=harfbuzz");`but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I have found that it will executed something like that  `cc -m64 -Wl,--eh-frame-hdr -Wl,-znoexecstack -Wl,--as-needed -L /usr/lib64/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib ... -L /usr/lib -L /usr/lib64/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib -lharfbuzz -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,--whole-archive -lmyharfbuzz -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,... -lpthread -lm -ldl -lc
` , and the linking problem happened there.

Comment: The problem is in the order of the options: you have `-lharfbuzz` _before_ `-lmyharfbuzz` but it should come after.

Comment: I rearranged the order in build.rs `println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", out_dir);     println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=myharfbuzz");     println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/usr/lib");     println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=harfbuzz");`
and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Linking with `#[link]` directive is unlikely to work, because Rust will not put any effort into searching where the given library is installed.

For linking with C/system dependencies you should be using sys crates. There is [harfbuzz-sys](https://lib.rs/crates/harfbuzz-sys).